# Django can't migrate to a new db

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations, apple-m1

I created a new postgreSQL database and ran "python manage.py migrate" on a Django project with no migration files. This error showed up :

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_model_name" does not exist
```

I tried makemigrations, showmigrations, runserver, and shell and it still gave me the same error. How do I fix this?

I am also using a Macbook Air with the M1 Chip.

Update: I don’t think this is caused by the M1 Chip because I was able to migrate/makemigrations in another project of mine. This is the initial error I got:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "app_model_name" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Rosetta because this was an M1 related issue.

```sh
arch -x86_64 python manage.py makemigrations 
arch -x86_64 python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all migration files from app/migrations
Then makemigrations
Then migrate

Comment: I don’t have any migration files

Comment: From what I see in stack there is some issue with postgres and m1 chip